# Maximum length of a relationship in a multi relational graph

Tags: neo4j, cypher

My query to find the maximum depth of the graph is like this:

```
match (n)<-[rel:shares|comments*0..]-(m) where id(n)=69 return max(length(rel))
```

The problem with this is it takes forever to return the depth. Any suggestion to speed this?

Answer (score 1):

How dense is your node ?

```
MATCH (n) WHERE id(n) = 69
RETURN size((n)--())
```

The `length()` function don't apply on relationships or collections of relationships, you can either use it on a path or use `size()` on the collection of relationships

```
MATCH (n) WHERE id(n) = 69
MATCH p=(n)<-[:shares|:comment*]-(x)
RETURN max(length(p))
```

or

```
MATCH (n) WHERE id(n) = 69
MATCH p=(n)<-[rel:shares|:comment*]-(x)
RETURN max(size(rel))
```

Would be nice also if you could share the query plan profile.

Note, on big graphs this can be a huuuge operation and might require a good machine to compute in a reasonnable time.